# Out of Memory Lambda Compile versus inline delegates

Tags: c#, performance, linq, lambda, expression-trees

Using 4.5.1 with an application that on the server side shuffles chart data with many REST requests simultaneously.

Use IQueryable to build queries.  For example, I **originally** had the following:

```
 var query = ctx.Respondents
   .Join(
     ctx.Respondents,
     other => other.RespondentId,
     res => res.RespondentId,
     (other, res) => new ChartJoin { Respondent = res, Occasion = null, BrandVisited = null, BrandInfo = null, Party = null, Item = null }
   )
   . // bunch of other joins filling out the ChartJoin
   .Where(x => x.Respondent.status == 1)
   . // more Where clauses dynamically applied
   .GroupBy(x => new CommonGroupBy { Year = (int)x.Respondent.currentVisitYear, Month = (int)x.Respondent.currentVisitMonth })
   .OrderBy(x => x.Key.Year)
   .ThenBy(x => x.Key.Month)
   .Select(x => new AverageEaterCheque
     {
       Year = x.Key.Year,
       Month = x.Key.Month,
       AverageCheque = (double)(x.Sum(m => m.BrandVisited.DOLLAR_TOTAL) / x.Sum(m => m.BrandVisited.NUM_PAID)),
       Base = x.Count(),
       Days = x.Select(m => m.Respondent.visitDate).Distinct().Count()
   });
```

To allow for dynamic grouping (via the client), the GroupBy was generated with C# expressions returning a Dictionary.  The Select also had to be generated with expressions.  The above Select became something like:

```
 public static Expression<Func<IGrouping<IDictionary<string, object>, ChartJoin>, AverageEaterCheque>> GetAverageEaterChequeSelector()
 {
    // x => 
    var ParameterType = typeof(IGrouping<IDictionary<string, object>, ChartJoin>);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(ParameterType);

    // x => x.Sum(m => m.BrandVisited.DOLLAR_TOTAL) / x.Sum(m => m.BrandVisited.NUM_PAID)
    var m = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ChartJoin), "m");

    var mBrandVisited = Expression.PropertyOrField(m, "BrandVisited");

    PropertyInfo DollarTotalPropertyInfo = typeof(BrandVisited).GetProperty("DOLLAR_TOTAL");
    PropertyInfo NumPaidPropertyInfo = typeof(BrandVisited).GetProperty("NUM_PAID");

    ....

    return a lambda...
 }
```

When I did a test run locally I got an Out of Memory error.  Then I started reading blogs from [Totin](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/07/24/unusual-ways-of-boosting-up-app-performance-lambdas-and-linqs/) and others that Lambda compiles, expression trees in general are expensive.  Had no idea it would blow my application.  And I need the ability to dynamically add grouping which lead me to using Expression trees for the GroupBy and Select clauses.

Would love some pointers on how to chase down the memory offenders in my application?  Have seen some people use dotMemory but would be great with some practical tips as well.  Very little experience in monitoring C#, DotNet.

Comment: I would first check the data being returned by your EF query. That is more likely the memory hog than the expression.

Comment: The code that you shown isn't using the expression that you're building at all.  How could we tell you what you're doing wrong with the code you haven't shown us?

Comment: @Servy, the question shows the hard-coded GroupBy and Select clauses written as inline lambda then a brief example of writing a Select clause with Expressions.  That switch over is when I noticed the memory problems.

Comment: @user1620220, I downloaded dotMemory and profiled.  Looks like String and Dictionary objects are eating up Generation 2.  Maybe a Dictionary (which is passed from the GroupBy into the Select) is not a good choose for a "dynamic" structure?

Comment: Generation 2 is 99% utilized.  Have to read up the C# heap.

Comment: @MatthewYoung So don't you think showing us the code that's *not* working is more important than showing us the code that *is* working?  If we can't see the code that isn't working, how can we possibly show you what you did wrong when writing it?  Had you written the code properly, it would function identically to the code that you've shown.  Clearly you didn't; you made a mistake somewhere.  Until you show us the code, we can't point it out to you.

Comment: When I suggested looking at your data, I meant how many rows and columns are you processing? You probably want to offload this processing to your database as much as possible, so maybe a stored procedure is appropriate here.

Comment: @user1620220 The query that he has shown does *all* of its data processing on the database, not on the application side of things.

Comment: @Servy, I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/489efd095740a386391b) which shows a working "hard-coded" query that is memory friendly.

Comment: @Servy Are you certain about that? I believe there are some conditions that prevent EF from generating SQL and force execution in memory.

Comment: @user1620220 I'm certain that the code that he posted here will be run as SQL.  I'm quite confident that in the code that he re-wrote that is failing is failing precisely because in his attempt to re-write it, he prevented it from doing with the code shown here does, namely being translated into SQL.

Comment: @user1620220 The point is that the code actually in the question will not pull down the data into memory.  It was the error in the code not shown in the question, namely the explicit compiling of the expression, that caused the "incorrect" overload of the LINQ operations to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're compiling the expression into a delegate, the operation is performed using LINQ to Objects, rather than using the `IQueryable` overload.  This means that the entirety of the data set is being pulled into memory, and all of the processing done by the application, instead of that processing being done in the database and only the final results being sent to the application.

Apparently pulling down the entire table into memory is enough to run your application out of memory.

You need to *not* compile the lambda, and leave it as an expression, thus allowing the query provider to translate it into SQL, as is done with your original code.

Comment: at line 20 in my Gist I can remove the Compile call in the GroupBy clause.  However, I can not remove it from the Select clause at line 28.  This is why Compile is littered all over the place.  Is there a problem with my method signature?

Comment: @MatthewYoung It's quite important that you not compile any of the expressions.  By compiling them into delegates you force the code into LINQ-to-Objects.  You need it to use EF, and be translated into SQL code.  That can't happen if you compile the expressions.

Comment: I thin you are on to the root problem.  Got an error when removing Compile() from the Group By in that LINQ to Entities doesn't recognize my dictionary object and the method can't not be translated into a store expression.

Comment: when I said I "can't" remove the Compile call from line 28 it is the compiler saying just GetAveragePartySizeSelector() is invalid in the Select clause.

Comment: @MatthewYoung Then you need to figure out why.  In this case, the error message makes it fairly clear.  You don't have an `IQueryable`, you have an `IEnumerable`, meaning you're doing something earlier to convert your query into an in-memory sequence.  Your methods are using `IEnumerable`, not `IQueryable`, thus ensuring all of your operations act on an in-memory collection.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out IEnumerable, IQueryable mix-up.  Read more about their [differences](http://blog.falafel.com/understanding-ienumerable-iqueryable-c/).

Comment: There are quite a few technical errors in that blog post.  I wouldn't rely on it too much.  It's not *terrible*, but it's certainly not great, and has a somewhat limited view of the true capacity of the types it discusses.