# Creating Linq to EF types for GroupBy Key selector

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, expression-trees

Using Net 4.5.1

Ran into a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404158/out-of-memory-lambda-compile-versus-inline-delegates) with the construction of Queryable that mixed in Enumerable lambda compilations that was pulling everything from the database into memory.  Thanks @Servy for the help there.

I was using a dictionary as the TKey in a GroupBy selector I created with expressions.  A dictionary apparently can't be used in this fashion (see [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/489efd095740a386391b) line 37 **GetGroupByDictionary** method).  Tried with a simple object array and ran into type conversion problems (i.e. EF expects primitive or Enum).  Tested a hard-code array of Int but the TKey selector type for the GroupBy isn't handled by the provider (i.e. database).  The GroupBy in the Queryable looked like:

```
 GroupBy(Param_0 => 
   new [] {
     Convert(Param_0.Respondent.currentVisitYear),
     Convert(Param_0.Respondent.currentVisitMonth)
 })
```

My intent was to use either a dictionary or array to house an unknown number of group-by key selector (i.e. the client decides what to group by which can be one property or 10).

Can these types for a key selector can ever be valid/used when going from Linq to EF?

If I new in advance the number of group-by then an anonymous type would do, like:

```
 .GroupBy(x => 
    new { 
      Year = x.Respondent.currentVisitYear, 
      Month = x.Respondent.currentVisitMonth
    } 
  )
```

It is possible to create types at runtime (thanks this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606104/how-to-create-linq-expression-tree-with-anonymous-type-in-it)).  Is this my only alternative?

**Update**
Made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c3170f255e3f9da857d3) with the help of Ethan J. Brown's code to create an type on the fly as the TSource result of the GroupBy clause.  At line 9 in [Calling Method](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c3170f255e3f9da857d3#file-calling-method) I create the IGrouping returning the type and Expression in a Tuple.  At line 24 I create the Select clause's selector expression.

Everything compiles but bombs out when with:

```
 {"The LINQ expression node type 'Lambda' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."}
```

If I rip out the dynamic type (i.e. hard-code an inline lambda in the GroupBy) with a normal type:

```
 GroupBy(x=> new CommonGroupBy( 
   Year : (int) x.Respondent.currentVisitYear,
   Month : (int) x.Respondent.currentVisitMonth
 )
```

and adjust the selector code to return (i.e. CommonGroupBy rather than object):

```
 Expression<Func<IGrouping<CommonGroupBy, ChartJoin>, AveragePartySize>>
```

then the query runs.  Something in the hand off of dynamic types isn't right.

**Update 2**
The error above was due to line 32 in the [Group by stuff](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c3170f255e3f9da857d3#file-group-by-stuff-dynamic) file.  Right now battling with the next error:

```
 "Unable to cast the type 'System.Object' to type 'Year;Nullable`1;Month;Nullable`1;'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."
```

Comment: Using an inline lambda with an Array (new [] {}) there is a provider error.  Dictionary is not an acceptable type of List and Tuples their Create call isn't accepted by the EF as well their constructor can't have parameters (i.e. new [] { new Tuple<string,int>("Year", x.Respondent.currentVisitYear) ...}).

Comment: List in the GroupBy bomb out as well (new List<int> { (int)x.Respondent.currentVisitYear, (int)x.Respondent.currentVisitMonth}) since the key selector type for GroupBy is not support by the underlying provider.

Comment: Got it working now.  Will post later on Gist my code.